# Magento attribute type date displaying wrong format on front-end

Tags: magento, attributes

I created a date attribute with date type as date. In the admin the date format is MM/DD/YYYY but when the date appears on the front-end of the product page the date format is DD/MM/YYYY

Any insight on how to get the front-end to match the admin would be great. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Post the code you are using to display the date on the frontend.

Comment: $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM);

Comment: My locale(System>Config>General>Locale Options>Locale) settings in Magento is set to English(United States). It only display the correct format when i change the locale to English(United Kingdom). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the date helper:

```
$fromDate = '2011-12-11';
echo $formattedDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')
    ->date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fromDate))
;
```

Although the issue may be due to the locale settings changing the default date format.

Comment: It looks like this is what is occurring. When I change local settings to English(UK) it displays correct date but the format is DD/MM/YY.

Comment: How can I fix this? So if i set to locale settings to English(US) it displays the format as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: yeah, for example UK/GB will use dd/mm/yy and I think USA uses mm/dd/yyyy